# Login with PayPal call back event after login

Tags: .net, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-ipn

I have successfully logging to PayPal and my  `returnurl` receive the pay pal data (code=xxxxxxxxxx&scope=email ,
but i need to receive this data on the client side.

Do paypal have some event like
`login.successful(response){} ,login.submit(response){}` ? some successful login event where i get see the sode =xxxxx  that paypal sent to my `returnurl`

I need to receive this data not only at my `returnurl` , i need it at my client side.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
            <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <span id='cwppButton'></span>
    <script src='https://www.paypalobjects.com/js/external/connect/api.js'></script>
    <script>
    paypal.use( ['login'], function (login) {

      login.render ({
       "appid":"xxx-xxx",
        "authend":"sandbox",
        "scopes":"email address profile",
        "containerid":"cwppButton",
        "responseType":"code",
        "locale":"en-us",
        "buttonType":"CWP",
        "buttonShape":"pill",
        "buttonSize":"lg",
        "fullPage":"false",
        "returnurl":"https://xxxx/"
      });

      console.log("login : "+JSON.stringify(login));//login : {"build":16}

    });




    </script>
            </head>

        <body>




        </body>

    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only way that i had found is to use *returnurl* parameter to receive the response.

You need to build service/controller that will receive the data from response and send it back to your page.

This is how i did it:

My *returnurl* send data to my controller,i work with this data ,and then i send request to my page with query-string that i have build from pay pal data that i had received,and read it on my page (PageLoad event)

This is not the best way ,but it working.If you have another way to do this please let me know.

```
 public void PayPalLisiner()
    {
        try
        {
       //get pay pal data
       string AuthorizationCode = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["code"];

      //my function that work with data,and prepare query-string 
      string PayPalLogin = privateZoneService.PayPalLogin(AuthorizationCode);

      //set request with query-string parameters
      HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("http://demo.com/login?PayPalLogin=" + PayPalLogin);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.Error(ex.Message);
        }

    }
```